# Parse error in pattern: putStrLn Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Hakell and is getting Following error when i am trying to execute the program.

Parse error in pattern: putStrLn
Possibly caused by a missing 'do'?

```
import Data.List  
import System.IO  

main=do  
    putStrLn"Enter your name"  
    name<-getLine  
    putStrLn("m, "++name)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you happen to have tabs in your source code?

Comment: Thanks,that was the problem

Comment: @chi  Can you post this as an answer and  Kent mark it as accepted please.